# Can't load trained pytorch model (.pt) due to ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning.accelerators.cuda'. Is there a way to rescue it?

Tags: pytorch, pickle, pytorch-lightning

I want to load a trained pytorch model that was saved using torch.save(PATH.pt). The model was trained using pytorch lightning. I could load and evaluate it right after training it with no problem. But now i can't because I get the following Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 6 torch.load(model.pt)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Env1\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:712, in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    710             opened_file.seek(orig_position)
    711             return torch.jit.load(opened_file)
--> 712         return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
    713 return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Env1\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1049, in _load(zip_file, map_location, pickle_module, pickle_file, **pickle_load_args)
   1047 unpickler = UnpicklerWrapper(data_file, **pickle_load_args)
   1048 unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
-> 1049 result = unpickler.load()
   1051 torch._utils._validate_loaded_sparse_tensors()
   1053 return result

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Env1\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1042, in _load.<locals>.UnpicklerWrapper.find_class(self, mod_name, name)
   1040         pass
   1041 mod_name = load_module_mapping.get(mod_name, mod_name)
-> 1042 return super().find_class(mod_name, name)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytorch_lightning.accelerators.cuda'
```

After googling the Error I realized that the way i saved this model was stupid and prone to these kind of errors. As written in the Documentation of pytorch:

> "torch.save(model, PATH) => This save/load process uses the most intuitive syntax and involves the least amount of code. Saving a model in this way will save the entire module using Python’s pickle module. The **disadvantage of this approach is that the serialized data is bound to the specific classes and the exact directory structure used when the model is saved.** The reason for this is because pickle does not save the model class itself. Rather, it saves a path to the file containing the class, which is used during load time. Because of this, your code can break in various ways when used in other projects or after refactors."

Despite that i would be really glad, if i could rescue this model since it was quite promissing. Is there away to access the model or its parameters despite the possible accured changes?

Comment: Could you provide the code where you are trying to load your model ?

Comment: I just use torch.load(model.pt) with model.pt beeing the path to the file